# What do you call an artwork that was not made specifically for a client?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for an artwork that was made exclusively to express an idea of the artist without him or her trying to tailor it to a specific audience.

The word *abstract* comes close because abstract paintings are usually not made for a specific client, but a painting of a landscape could also fit the description above.

Another word I've considered is *un-commissioned* art. This word comes very close, but the meaning seems more like *no-one paid for this* rather than *it was an original idea by the artist*.

The Dutch sentence I'm translating from is *Vrij werk* which literally translates to *Free work*. In English this would be interpreted as art one doesn't have to pay for (*free*) which isn't the meaning I'm looking for either.

**Example sentence**: ARTIST is famous for his WORD paintings, which only became highly appreciated and valued after his death. During his life ARTIST made both WORD and NOT-WORD paintings, but his only income came from the NOT-WORD art he occasionally made for noblemen.

Comment: Noncommissioned?

Comment: Unusual distinction, most famous Renaissance Italian painters  worked  almost exclusively for clients.

Comment: Your own suggestion of un-commissioned seems to be the best fit and IMHO does not suggest the artist was not paid, but that the artist created the painting on a whim, because they wanted to or they thought someone would be prepared to buy it; selling the painting at a later date to an interested buyer.

Comment: Noncomissioned seems like the best option so far. I also thought of *independent art*, *liberal art*, or *unconstrained art*, although those terms do not seem to be regularly used.

Comment: For the NOT-WORD: "painting on order".

Comment: I can’t give you an answer because I don’t believe there is or should be such a word.

In general, art is art. Specifically commissioned art, surely still the minority, should carry the burden of distinction, making the idea of un-commissioned art superfluous?

An analogy might be with clocks and watches which simply existed, until digital versions not only arrived, but later grabbed at least a huge share, if not the majority of the market. First traditional and then analog became first useful and then necessary not because of the difference but because digital had grown so large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the restrictive adjective is indeed describing a restriction, the lack of a restriction should be most appropriate.

> Pablo's art is eye-catching, especially his commissioned work for MOMA.

Answer (score 2):

One common way to express this idea is to say that the artwork was created "**on spec**", a shortened form of "on speculation".  This sense of the word "spec" is defined by [Oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spec?q=on%20spec) as "in the hope of success but without any specific plan or instructions".

That site also gives this example sentence:

> I wrote my first book on spec, sent it off to nearly 100 publishers
>   and in six weeks I had my first offer.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***inspired***?  [Jackson Pollock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Pollock), for example, didn't have a commission for a drip painting.  He was inspired to create this new form.

Pollock did have [commissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Pollock) pre-drip, and worked for the WPA Federal Art Project from 1938 to 1942.

Inspired, from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inspired)

> aroused, animated, or imbued with the spirit to do something, by or
>   as if by supernatural or divine influence: an inspired poet. 2.
>   resulting from such inspiration : an inspired poem; an inspired plan.